# can't read property 'renderSubCategory' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Below is my component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {megaNavContent} from '../actions'

class MegaNavComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderSubCategory = this.renderSubCategory.bind(this);
    this.megaNavRender = this.megaNavRender.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.megaNavContent("Row");
  } 
  megaNavRender(){
    var list = [];
    const MegaNavData = this.props.content.Row4;
    if(MegaNavData != null && MegaNavData.categorie){
      const Categories = MegaNavData.categorie
      Categories.forEach(function(category){
        list.push(
          <li>
            <a href="#">{category.name}</a>
            <ul className="dummy">
              <li className="dummy">
                <ul className="dl-submenu" id="mob-navi-ul">
                  <li>
                    {this.renderSubCategory(category)}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        )
      })      
    } 
  return list;
  }
  renderSubCategory(){
    var cat = []
    console.log("looking for subcategory")
    const subCategory = category.data;
    subCategory.forEach(function(sub){
     cat.push(<ul>{sub}</ul>);         
    })
    return cat;
  }
  render(){
    const MegaNavData = this.props.content.Row;
    return(
      <div>
        <ul className="dl-menu">
          {this.megaNavRender()} 
        </ul>  
      </div>
        );
      }
    }

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    content : state.content
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{megaNavContent})(MegaNavComponent);
```

From the above code, I want to call renderSubCategory and get some HTML/JSX to display, but getting the error.

Also, Is there a better way to write above megaNavRender() function to loop through JSON. i.e forEach(HTML/JSX(forEach(HTML/JSX(forEach(HTML/JSX)))))
instead of having many callbacks called for every forEach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions declared with `function` keyword has their own `this` context, so `this` inside `Categories.forEach(function(category){` does not refer to the class. You can use `arrow` syntax for function declaration which will laxically resolve value of `this`. Change

`Categories.forEach(function(category){`

to

`Categories.forEach((category) => {`

Comment: Thanks @Prakash this works, do u know any better way to solve my other issue that I mentioned in my post at bottom.

Comment: @praveen I dont think there is any better way of doing this as you want to render them nested.
Also instead of `forEach`, you can use `map` function. That way you wont have to maintain a variable and push element to that. You can simply do `return Categories.map((category) => {`